# Get html files path in other package inserted html in alpine js component based architecture

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules

I am trying to build component wise application using alpine js using same as what react offers as a default to kind of isolating code in pieces.

However when i am trying to inject html in other module i am not getting the node_modules path in the html.
What is the correct way to get the html templates path if my own package is inside node_module folder and html files are inside them which are finally going to be injected inside page.

This is the javascript from my own package which i am trying to export.

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import path from 'path';
import main from './components/main/main';

window.Alpine = Alpine;
import component from 'alpinejs-component';
Alpine.plugin(component)


Alpine.start();




function mainComponentHtml() {
  
  return `
    
      <div>
        <x-component url="${require.resolve('./components/main/main.html')}" x-data="${main}"></x-component> 
      </div>
    
  `;
}
  
export { main, mainComponentHtml};
```

and here is how i am importing and injecting in other project.

```
import {mainComponentHtml} from 'my-own-local-package';

document.body.innerHTML = mainComponentHtml();
```

`main.html` is at `node_modules/my-own-package/src/components/main/main.html`.

As we can see main.html is inside `node_modules` which is rendered incorrectly when inserted inside browser.

I am using webpack bundler and it;s own devServer and there might be some techniques specific to this but i need full fledged way(irrespective of server used) so that html always points to the correct node_module's package(my own package in this case) path when rendered in browser.